# Does the SymEigsShiftSolver of Spectra not return eigenvectors?

Tags: c++, eigen, lapack, armadillo, eigen3

I have implemented the SymEigsShiftSolver for computing the eigenvalues of a large sparse matrix, however it does not return me the eigenvectors. Has it not been implemented as of yet?

```
void Eigens::computeEigenvectors(Matrices m)
{
SparseSymShiftSolve<double> op(m.Lpl);
SymEigsShiftSolver< double, SMALLEST_MAGN, SparseSymShiftSolve<double> >
            eigs(&op, k, 4, 0.0);
eigs.init();
int nconv = eigs.compute();
VectorXd evalues;
evalues.resize(k);
if(eigs.info() == SUCCESSFUL)
    evalues = eigs.eigenvalues();
cout << "Eigenvalues found:\n" << evalues << endl;
cout <<"\nHere is the matrix whose columns are eigenvectors of the Laplacian Matrix \n"
     <<"corresponding to these eigenvalues: \n"
     <<eigs.eigenvectors()<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you've added the "armadillo" tag, since you're using the eigen library.  I've provided the following response if you are indeed interested in an [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) based solution.

Both Armadillo and Spectra use very similar underlying code for sparse eigendecomposition (the code was written by the same author), but Armadillo has a simplified user interface. To compute the eigenvectors of a symmetric sparse matrix using Armadillo, use the [eigs_sym()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eigs_sym) function:

```
// generate sparse symmetric matrix
sp_mat A = sprandu<sp_mat>(5000, 5000, 0.1);
sp_mat B = A.t()*A;

vec eigval;
mat eigvec;

eigs_sym(eigval, eigvec, B, 5);       // find 5 eigenvectors with largest magnitude
eigs_sym(eigval, eigvec, B, 5, "sm"); // find 5 eigenvectors with smallest magnitude
```

If you have a non-symmetric matrix, the [eigs_gen()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eigs_gen) function can be used in a similar manner:

```
sp_mat A = sprandu<sp_mat>(5000, 5000, 0.1);  

cx_vec eigval;
cx_mat eigvec;

eigs_gen(eigval, eigvec, A, 5);  // find 5 eigenvalues/eigenvectors
```

A [sparse matrix](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#SpMat) can be constructed from a 1D array in a simple manner:

```
double data[nrows * ncols]; // 1D array representation of your matrix

sp_mat X = sp_mat( mat(data, nrows, ncols, false) );
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. The SymEigsShiftSolver requires a sigma value of >0 in order to return the eigenvectors.

```
 SymEigsShiftSolver< double, SMALLEST_MAGN, SparseSymShiftSolve<double> >
            eigs(&op, k, 4, 1.0);
```